# Using Linq on an ICollection with Date Comparison

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am using the standard ApplicationUser, and I've enhanced the model with public virtual IColliction profiles;

E.g

```
public class ApplicationUser(){
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Profile> profiles;
}
```

My profile Model:

```
public class Profile(){
    public Guid ID;
    ...
    public System.DateTime ValidFrom;
    public System.DateTime ValidTo;    
}
```

I'm looking to set a never ending date of 31/12/9999 for the ValidTo Date of the profile. I wanted to get the profile within a profile controller.

I tried the following:

```
System.DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Parse("31/12/9999");

            string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
            Profile profile = currentUser.Profiles.Select(s => s.ValidityEndDate >= EndDate);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'datex.Models.Profile'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing
>   a cast?)

I'm assuming that I'm definitely not the right track, can someone please help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select` returns an IEnumerable, not a single Profile object. You should either use `FirstOrDefault`, eg `.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ValidityEndDate >= EndDate)` or change the type of the `profile` variable to accept an `IEnumerable<Profile>`.

Dates have nothing to do with this error, although using a locale-specific string in `DateTime.Parse` can cause issued down the road. In this particular case you could use [DateTime.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of hard-coding the date

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, thank you very much for your quick reply. That has worked - thank you for the tip on the DateTime.MaxValue. I'll use that instead of string parsing.